# URI Malformed - New Firebase Serve (React Js)

Tags: firebase

Trying to get my head around firebase hosting.

I have followed what should be a simple set up but I am getting this error every time I try and use Firebase serve (localhost:5000) or firebase Deploy (address.web.app)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURI (<anonymous>)
    at Responder.provider (C:\Users\gibso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\superstatic\lib\providers\fs.js:71:16)
    at C:\Users\gibso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\superstatic\lib\middleware\files.js:225:37
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2022:08:36:46 +0000] "GET /%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 - "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try changing public folder to build? Change

```
"hosting": {
....
    "public": "public",
....
}
```

to

```
"hosting": {
....
    "public": "build",
....
}
```

in firebase.json file?

Comment: Thanks, I'm rather new to this and realised that it was due to not running a build beforehand. Your answer pushed me in the right direction though!