# How to host React app with Firebase emulator

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-tools

I am trying to get an already functioning webapp with firebase deployment going on a new pc, I am using VS code with Node on Windows. When I run `yarn start`, it executed fine on the port 3000. When I use `firebase emulators:start` on some port, for example 5033 it doesn't show anything. I am using `"hosting": { "public": "public",` in the firebase configuration file. My question is what should I do to make the functioning React app be hosted on a firebase emulator? Maybe I should change something in the `index.html` in the public folder, but I have no clue.
I am new to web development, so detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated.

When `firebase emulators:start` is running I get `URIError: URI malformed` in the terminal

Comment: What is the output of `firebase emulators:start --debug`? What are the contents of your firebase.json file? Where does `5033` come from, is it in the firebase.json? Does the old method `firebase serve --only hosting` work at all?

Comment: firebase serve --only hosting produces URI malformed error as well and a completely empty page. 5033 comes from firebase.json, I can change it to a different number, but doesn't seem to have an effect.  For debug I get
`│ Emulator │ Host:Port      │
├──────────┼────────────────┤
│ Hosting  │ 127.0.0.1:5033 │
└──────────┴────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.

i  hosting: 127.0.0.1 -***
URIError: URI malformed`

Comment: Firebase configuration is:
`{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5033
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}`

Comment: If you don't need to connect to prod for firestore/RTDB/etc try this demo project: `firebase emulators:start --debug --project=demo-testing`. If you do need to connect to prod, ensure you're using the correct project ID (check with `firebase use`)

Comment: I get the same `URIError: URI malformed` with `firebase emulators:start --debug --project=demo-testing` as well. What does it mean? projectID seems to be fine

Comment: Here's a similar question that might be helpful that recommends swapping to "public":"build" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708016/uri-malformed-new-firebase-serve-react-js

Comment: I've tried to switch back and forth as a first measure to no avail unfortunately

Comment: In that case there may be a bug here - I'd recommend filing an issue here with reproducible steps: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/new/choose

Please be as detailed as you can so the team can identify the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I figured out at least partially how to solve it and the app works. It seems the problem was with the build folder. After using `yarn build` and `firebase deploy` it finally worked as expected. After `firebase init` the build folder was overwritten. No idea, why it didn't work out at all, I guess I've changed something in the build. Anyway take care to build the folder which is then deployed with Firebase.